# URL in a request is changed before run

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, browser

I have a problem when I try to run a http request where my NodeJS application for some odd reason decides to add my domain to the URL that I have set in my http request. How do I make sure this does not happen?

I tried searching for similar issues but found none. Might be that I am unsure of what to actually search for.

Here is what I want to have run:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx',
    type: 'PUT',
    headers: {
        'value': 'value',
        'value2': 'value2' 
    },
    success: function(result) {
        // extra code...
    }
});
```

And this is what happens in the request, as seen from console:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost:8080/xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx', // (added localhost)
    type: 'PUT',
    headers: {
       'value': 'value',
       'value2': 'value2' 
    },
    success: function(result) {
        // extra code...
    }
});
```

Worth noting (maybe) is that if I add http:// to my request URL it does not change when run, but that URL is not accepted. This request is to be run on the client side of things, ie in the browser.

Comment: is `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` an url to another website?

Comment: Maybe you could try using `//xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx`?

Comment: It is, or well it's an URL to a server. I tried with // and that worked, but realised that I had to add a port as well, something that seems impossible with a normal AJAX-request in browser. So now I need to find a new solution...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You URL is not quite a valid URL because it is missing a scheme and possibly other bits as well, so ajax is taking a best guess at what you meant.

The default for ajax() is to query the current page, which is http://localhost:8080, and it took what you supplied as being a path on that page.

Try this instead:

> url: 'http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx',

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I actually did not know that you had to add a protocol when using IP-addresses directly. Sadly http:// is not working for me, I realised that I had to add a port as well, something that seems impossible with a normal AJAX-request in browser. So now I need to find a new solution...

Answer (score 0):

That is the difference between absolute url and relative url. A url without its protocol is considered a relative url and so the following will happen.

Relative URL: user/1

Current Location: http://google.com/products

Result: http://google.com/products/user/1

or

Relative URL: /user/1

Current Location: http://google.com/products

Result: http://google.com/user/1

Answer (score 0):

if `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` is an url to another website, you'll have to specify the protocol or `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` will be interpretted as relative path.

In general this applies to `src` attributes as well (for `img`, `srcipt` and `iframe` ...). Any links in the page will be regarded as relative paths unless their protocol is specified.

**For example: (just for explanation)** on Windows if you have a path like `some\thing`, it will be relative to wherever you are trying to access it (the absolute path of where you are trying to access it will be automatically prepended to the path `some\thing`). But if your path is `C:\some\thing`, then it will be always the same wherever it is accessed. The protocols works in similar ways.

Comment: You explained this perfectly, thank you! I am now looking for a different solution, so I am not sure if I should pick an answer as solution or just let it be for a bit.